# How are get and set methods on javabeans called by frameworks?

Tags: java, javabeans

If you have a bean with a `getFoo` method, how does whatever framework you're using know how to call the `getFoo` method when you ask for the value of `foo`? Is this done using the reflection API? Or is it somehow done using annotations? Obviously I know how you can derive the method given the name of the property, I just don't know how the method is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses "properties" by method name convention.  For a property `camelCase` of type `T` you should define one or both of `public T getCamelCase()` and `public void setCamelCase(T t)`.  You can test properties on a bean with this code:

```
Introspector.getBeanInfo (bean.getClass ()).getPropertyDescriptors ();
```

Note that because properties are not first-class objects and rely on naming convention, it is easy to accidentally break such pseudoproperty.  E.g. if you define `setFoo(int)` and `setFoo(int, boolean)` there will be no property `foo` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

The actual method invocation is indeed done through reflection. You can have for instance a look at [BeanUtil](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/index.html) and more especally [MethodUtil](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/beanutils/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.java?view=markup) sources. To invoke a method reflectively, you use

```
 method.invoke( bean, parameters );
```

See the [reflection tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) for examples.